# How to fix height the content inside a div with flex css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Following to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/275097) answer, I am trying to create a perfect height for my content, But the content height is overflowing instead of getting a scroll over content. 
I have created a fiddle for this scenario. Please help me fix my content height such a way that top content and always visible and scroll-able downward.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsd_codesode/899ws4uk/)

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
    border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.data {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.box .row.footer {
    flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

HTML.

```
<head>
    <link href="./test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="row header">
            <p>
                <b>header</b>
                <br />
                <br />(sized to content)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="data">
                invisible box1
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                visible box2
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                visible box3
            </div>
            <p>
                <b>Bottom Box is visible with scroll.</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row footer">
            <p>
                <b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As this works for me on Firefox and Chrome, which browser do you use?

Comment: chrome only latest. Please see the fiddle, Are you able to see, first div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use safe center with flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635911/how-to-use-safe-center-with-flexbox)

Comment: its working for me too in Chrome

Comment: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u8js4dLr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you encounter is caused by `justify-content: center` in the `.box .row.content` rule.

Remove it and your text will overflow properly.

```
.box .row.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /*justify-content: center;              removed  */
    align-items: center;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/899ws4uk/2/)

---

This is the default behavior for `justify-content: center`, where, on a flex column container, when the content overflow, it will overflow both at its top and bottom.

Read more here, where you find resources and a workaround:

- [How to use safe center with flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635911/how-to-use-safe-center-with-flexbox/47636238#47636238)

Answer (score 0):

I think `overflow: scroll;` will fix your problem.

Comment: Nope, that won't solve anything. Check my answer if you want to know more.